# How to code multiple time intervals by a set of dates?

Tags: r, date, time

Searched SO for duplicate questions and a couple came close, but not quite to my problem. I tried implementing their solutions and the data are still not quite right.

1. **Summary:**
   I have a very long data set with multiple entries per subject ID, and they take place **in sets of intervals over the course of sets of three days.** See data below for exact detail.

- A subject might have 26 "intervals" over the course of 3 dates, and then has an outcome variable I need counted then scaled according to a "perfect" interval = 30. I.e. *whatever their count of X over the interval needs to be scaled as if it were done in 30 intervals over the course of the three consecutive dates.*
- Importantly, I need to tally the number of "S" and "U" to create their own separate counts as primary outcomes - this is the number that is getting "scaled" to a full 30 intervals per 3 days.

2. **I tried** (and failed) with sapply, for loops and some brute Excel stuff, but there are so many thousands of rows that doing it in Excel would take days.
3. **Some dummy data to work with:**

```r
> head(diary_df1, 30)
        id site      date count    type      interval
1  1280003   51 11/6/2013     0    None 06:00 - 08:00
2  1280003   51 11/6/2013     0    None 00:00 - 06:00
3  1280003   51 11/6/2013     1       S 08:00 - 10:00
4  1280003   51 11/6/2013     1       S 10:00 - 12:00
5  1280003   51 11/6/2013     0    None 12:00 - 14:00
6  1280003   51 11/6/2013     2     S S 14:00 - 16:00
7  1280003   51 11/6/2013     2     S S 16:00 - 18:00
8  1280003   51 11/6/2013     1       S 18:00 - 20:00
9  1280003   51 11/7/2013     0    None 00:00 - 06:00
10 1280003   51 11/7/2013     0    None 06:00 - 08:00
11 1280003   51 11/7/2013     1       S 08:00 - 10:00
12 1280003   51 11/7/2013     0    None 10:00 - 12:00
13 1280003   51 11/7/2013     2     S S 12:00 - 14:00
14 1280003   51 11/7/2013     1       S 14:00 - 16:00
15 1280003   51 11/7/2013     0    None 16:00 - 18:00
16 1280003   51 11/7/2013     2     S S 18:00 - 20:00
17 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 00:00 - 06:00
18 1280003   51 11/8/2013     2     S S 06:00 - 08:00
19 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 08:00 - 10:00
20 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 10:00 - 12:00
21 1280003   51 11/8/2013     1       S 12:00 - 14:00
22 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 14:00 - 16:00
23 1280003   51 11/8/2013     1       S 20:00 - 22:00
24 1280003   51 11/8/2013     1       S 22:00 - 00:00
25 1280003   51 11/8/2013     2     S S 16:00 - 18:00
26 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 18:00 - 20:00
27 1280003   51  4/1/2014     0    None 00:00 - 06:00
28 1280003   51  4/1/2014     0    None 06:00 - 08:00
29 1280003   51  4/1/2014     4 S S S S 08:00 - 10:00
30 1280003   51  4/1/2014     3   S S S 10:00 - 12:00
```

so this is 30 intervals, but as you can see in the 3 day span, the ppt only has **26 valid intervals before the date changes**

So, I would like to have additional columns that

1. spit out the count and total intervals over the time span, (**int_count**), (**int_tot**)
2. report that as a % of 30,  then
3. count the number of S and U (separately) in the type variable. (**x_3day_total**)

*DESIRED OUTCOME:*

```
> head(df_stack, 30)
        id site      date count    type      interval int_count int_tot x_3day_total
1  1280003   51 11/6/2013     0    None 06:00 - 08:00         1      26           20
2  1280003   51 11/6/2013     0    None 00:00 - 06:00         2      26           20
3  1280003   51 11/6/2013     1       S 08:00 - 10:00         3      26           20
4  1280003   51 11/6/2013     1       S 10:00 - 12:00         4      26           20
5  1280003   51 11/6/2013     0    None 12:00 - 14:00         5      26           20
6  1280003   51 11/6/2013     2     S S 14:00 - 16:00         6      26           20
7  1280003   51 11/6/2013     2     S S 16:00 - 18:00         7      26           20
8  1280003   51 11/6/2013     1       S 18:00 - 20:00         8      26           20
9  1280003   51 11/7/2013     0    None 00:00 - 06:00         9      26           20
10 1280003   51 11/7/2013     0    None 06:00 - 08:00        10      26           20
11 1280003   51 11/7/2013     1       S 08:00 - 10:00        11      26           20
12 1280003   51 11/7/2013     0    None 10:00 - 12:00        12      26           20
13 1280003   51 11/7/2013     2     S S 12:00 - 14:00        13      26           20
14 1280003   51 11/7/2013     1       S 14:00 - 16:00        14      26           20
15 1280003   51 11/7/2013     0    None 16:00 - 18:00        15      26           20
16 1280003   51 11/7/2013     2     S S 18:00 - 20:00        16      26           20
17 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 00:00 - 06:00        17      26           20
18 1280003   51 11/8/2013     2     S S 06:00 - 08:00        18      26           20
19 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 08:00 - 10:00        19      26           20
20 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 10:00 - 12:00        20      26           20
21 1280003   51 11/8/2013     1       S 12:00 - 14:00        21      26           20
22 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 14:00 - 16:00        22      26           20
23 1280003   51 11/8/2013     1       S 20:00 - 22:00        23      26           20
24 1280003   51 11/8/2013     1       S 22:00 - 00:00        24      26           20
25 1280003   51 11/8/2013     2     S S 16:00 - 18:00        25      26           20
26 1280003   51 11/8/2013     0    None 18:00 - 20:00        26      26           20
```

Note that this is only for a slice (26 rows) so it will need to apply per subject per 3 day set of dates (which can be longer or shorter than 26)

### Data (`dput`)

```
structure(list(id = c(1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 
1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 
1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 
1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 
1280003, 1280003, 1280003, 1280003), site = c(51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51), date = c("11/6/2013", 
"11/6/2013", "11/6/2013", "11/6/2013", "11/6/2013", "11/6/2013", 
"11/6/2013", "11/6/2013", "11/7/2013", "11/7/2013", "11/7/2013", 
"11/7/2013", "11/7/2013", "11/7/2013", "11/7/2013", "11/7/2013", 
"11/8/2013", "11/8/2013", "11/8/2013", "11/8/2013", "11/8/2013", 
"11/8/2013", "11/8/2013", "11/8/2013", "11/8/2013", "11/8/2013", 
"4/1/2014", "4/1/2014", "4/1/2014", "4/1/2014"), count = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3), type = c("None", "None", "S", "S", "None", 
"S S", "S S", "S", "None", "None", "S", "None", "S S", "S", "None", 
"S S", "None", "S S", "None", "None", "S", "None", "S", "S", 
"S S", "None", "None", "None", "S S S S", "S S S"), interval = c("06:00 - 08:00", 
"00:00 - 06:00", "08:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 14:00", 
"14:00 - 16:00", "16:00 - 18:00", "18:00 - 20:00", "00:00 - 06:00", 
"06:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 14:00", 
"14:00 - 16:00", "16:00 - 18:00", "18:00 - 20:00", "00:00 - 06:00", 
"06:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 10:00", "10:00 - 12:00", "12:00 - 14:00", 
"14:00 - 16:00", "20:00 - 22:00", "22:00 - 00:00", "16:00 - 18:00", 
"18:00 - 20:00", "00:00 - 06:00", "06:00 - 08:00", "08:00 - 10:00", 
"10:00 - 12:00")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please give a complete sample of those 26 intervals and in addition your expected output based on this input.

Comment: This seems like the sort of question I wouldn't want to try unless I knew ahead of time how the calculation worked and what output you wanted, otherwise we'll have to play chess by mail to get there. Please demonstrate an example calculation.

Comment: @MartinGal did the addition address your question?

Comment: @Walker Your `head(diary_df1, 30)` is hard to read in. Consider using `dput(head(diary_df1, 30)` which returns a `structure()` output. This is makes it very easy to read in.

Comment: Is it possible that there are more than three consecutive days?

Comment: @MartinGal Never more than 3 consecutive days - will edit with dput command. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  tibble() %>% 
  group_by(id, grp = cumsum(c(0, diff(mdy(date))) > 1)) %>% 
  mutate(int_count = row_number(),
         int_tot = n(),
         S_3day_total = sum(str_count(type, "S")),
         U_3day_total = sum(str_count(type, "U"))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

to get

```r
# A tibble: 30 x 11
        id  site date    count type  interval   grp int_count int_tot S_3day_total U_3day_total
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <int>     <int>   <int>        <int>        <int>
 1 1280003    51 11/6/2~     0 None  06:00 -~     0         1      26           20            0
 2 1280003    51 11/6/2~     0 None  00:00 -~     0         2      26           20            0
 3 1280003    51 11/6/2~     1 S     08:00 -~     0         3      26           20            0
 4 1280003    51 11/6/2~     1 S     10:00 -~     0         4      26           20            0
 5 1280003    51 11/6/2~     0 None  12:00 -~     0         5      26           20            0
 6 1280003    51 11/6/2~     2 S S   14:00 -~     0         6      26           20            0
 7 1280003    51 11/6/2~     2 S S   16:00 -~     0         7      26           20            0
 8 1280003    51 11/6/2~     1 S     18:00 -~     0         8      26           20            0
 9 1280003    51 11/7/2~     0 None  00:00 -~     0         9      26           20            0
10 1280003    51 11/7/2~     0 None  06:00 -~     0        10      26           20            0
11 1280003    51 11/7/2~     1 S     08:00 -~     0        11      26           20            0
12 1280003    51 11/7/2~     0 None  10:00 -~     0        12      26           20            0
13 1280003    51 11/7/2~     2 S S   12:00 -~     0        13      26           20            0
14 1280003    51 11/7/2~     1 S     14:00 -~     0        14      26           20            0
15 1280003    51 11/7/2~     0 None  16:00 -~     0        15      26           20            0
16 1280003    51 11/7/2~     2 S S   18:00 -~     0        16      26           20            0
17 1280003    51 11/8/2~     0 None  00:00 -~     0        17      26           20            0
18 1280003    51 11/8/2~     2 S S   06:00 -~     0        18      26           20            0
19 1280003    51 11/8/2~     0 None  08:00 -~     0        19      26           20            0
20 1280003    51 11/8/2~     0 None  10:00 -~     0        20      26           20            0
21 1280003    51 11/8/2~     1 S     12:00 -~     0        21      26           20            0
22 1280003    51 11/8/2~     0 None  14:00 -~     0        22      26           20            0
23 1280003    51 11/8/2~     1 S     20:00 -~     0        23      26           20            0
24 1280003    51 11/8/2~     1 S     22:00 -~     0        24      26           20            0
25 1280003    51 11/8/2~     2 S S   16:00 -~     0        25      26           20            0
26 1280003    51 11/8/2~     0 None  18:00 -~     0        26      26           20            0
27 1280003    51 4/1/20~     0 None  00:00 -~     1         1       4            7            0
28 1280003    51 4/1/20~     0 None  06:00 -~     1         2       4            7            0
29 1280003    51 4/1/20~     4 S S ~ 08:00 -~     1         3       4            7            0
30 1280003    51 4/1/20~     3 S S S 10:00 -~     1         4       4            7            0
```

- We group consecutive days together. But we don't check for exact three days. This might be a problem depending on your actual dataset.
- After grouping we create `int_count` and `int_total` using `dplyr` verbs and we count the number of `S` and `U` using `str_count` in two different columns.
- If you want to count both in one column, use `sum(str_count(type, "S|U"))` instead.